# View and Analyze Token Contracts on Solana

Tags: solscan

I'm new to the Solana ecosystem and have experience with Ethereum. On Ethereum, I usually use Etherscan to view and read smart contracts, particularly to understand their functionalities like buy and sell taxes, as seen in contracts like UNIBOT.

I'm interested in exploring similar functionalities within Solana-based tokens. Could you guide me on how to view Solana Token Contracts and examples of such contracts.

Comment: On Solana tokens are managed by the native Token Program (SPL). There are no seperate contracts for each token. See docs here - https://spl.solana.com/token

Comment: Thank you for the insight about the SPL Token Program. If I want to implement custom fee logic, like distributing fees for revenue sharing, liquidity pools, or a team wallet, how would I go about this on Solana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Solana not every token has its own smart contract. Instead there are two token programs. The SPL-Token and the Token22 aka Token Extensions program.

So most of them use the SPL TokenProgram for now.

https://spl.solana.com/token

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token

The way how you add different functionality to tokens on Solana is via token extensions:
https://solana.com/de/solutions/token-extensions

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions

So you can have interest bearing tokens, token transfer hooks, transfer fees etc.
To see the attributes of a token you just open them in one of the solana explorers.
This one for example has a transfer fee of 6.9%:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/CKfatsPMUf8SkiURsDXs7eK6GWb4Jsd6UDbs7twMCWxo
https://solscan.io/token/CKfatsPMUf8SkiURsDXs7eK6GWb4Jsd6UDbs7twMCWxo

You can find a video tutorial for every token extension here:

https://www.youtube.com/@SolanaFndn/videos